# Delete duplicates from company popups

Tags: company-mode, company

I use the following snippet to set up `company-mode` for text files and derived modes. I use a curated word list as the source for `company-ispell`.

```
(progn
  (defun sb/company-text-mode ()
    "Add backends for text completion in company mode."
    (setq-local company-minimum-prefix-length 2)
    (set (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
         '(company-files
           ;; FIXME: Delete duplicates
           ;; Give priority to dabbrev completions over ispell
           (:separate
            company-dabbrev
            company-ispell)
           )))

  (dolist (hook '(text-mode-hook)) ; Extends to derived modes like `markdown-mode' and `org-mode'
    (add-hook hook #'sb/company-text-mode)))
```

How can I avoid duplicates from appearing in `company` popups in cases where `company-dabbrev` returns a value? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try out setting `company-transformers` to `delete-dups`, as was suggested in one of the [`Company` threads](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/issues/528):

```lisp
(setq-local company-transformers '(delete-dups)
            company-backends '(company-files (:separate company-dabbrev company-ispell)))
```

It'd be interesting to know if you get any performance implications in case of large `ispell` backend candidates list.

Comment: Thanks. It should be `delete-dups`, isn't it?

Comment: I initially suggested `delete-consecutive-dups` for the case without `:separate` keyword. Now the answer is updated.